# geth stops syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, docker

I am running geth via docker `docker pull ethereum/client-go`. It stops syncing after serval days. After I reboot the docker, it works fine again. This situation happened serval times.

Here is the last log:

```
root@iZj6c0ta2ezu2yr0h25s2vZ:~# docker logs ethereum --tail 10
INFO [11-16|06:41:50.065] Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=62.482µs  number=6713685 hash=100ae4…29c92b ignored=1
INFO [11-16|06:41:50.358] Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=99.099µs  number=6713686 hash=65a710…e98470 ignored=2
INFO [11-16|06:42:16.176] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=6.304ms   number=6713687 hash=ada8c3…e7b959 ignored=0
INFO [11-16|06:42:27.040] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=6.256ms   number=6713688 hash=ae2fd3…7da368 ignored=0
INFO [11-16|06:43:05.968] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=6.353ms   number=6713689 hash=8a7613…915414 ignored=0
INFO [11-16|06:43:12.411] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=6.132ms   number=6713690 hash=d63ff3…656811 ignored=0
INFO [11-16|06:43:22.992] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=6.543ms   number=6713691 hash=89c3a4…ebdfb9 ignored=0
INFO [11-16|06:43:24.227] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=6.407ms   number=6713692 hash=af2fa2…866fb5 ignored=0
INFO [11-16|06:43:24.799] Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=61.444µs  number=6713692 hash=af2fa2…866fb5 ignored=1
INFO [11-16|06:55:29.082] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x6887d4ecd5198ca2d47856f3f1033f8ec0a19451267477dbf4af3d3d2886eace recipient=0x96D51aD581Cf6CB84Cef273334F51f4AB3ED5053
```

[image]

The highest block is 6773771 right now. The memory, cpu, hard disk seem working fine. At least i can't find any error log.

Any idea what is the problem?